# phonegap camera and android below 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

my phonegap app (with plugin camera) Works fine on recent android OS but when i tried to use it on android KitKat or any older OS i can select the image from the gallery but then the script wont grab it...any clues ? im guessing there is something wrong with the getPhoto() function....

my xml :

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1"/>
```

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}



 // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
  // Get image handle
  console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = imageData;  setTimeout(color, 1000);
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);
  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;



} 
// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoWithData() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}
function capturePhotoWithFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });


}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
      { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM });

}
// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
    function onSuccess (imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById ('smallImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block'; 
    largeImage.src = imageURI;


</script>
```

i am building on phonegap build and  i also tried on Intel XDK ...same result..not working on 4.4.2 and other 4.x OS

Comment: Whats the error in console trace?

Comment: Oh man im new to app dev... im not using any debuger (cant make it  work )   plus i was thinking that i needed to use the phone couse the problem is only when i use the phone gallery... i use in device ready on every html  page  of my app is it ok? Or i must use this func only once?

Comment: I dint understand your question at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the camera plugin and now works